# To check for the modified date of the file on file system and get the latest file

Tags: sql, filesystems

We have a SQL SSIS package setup which is being run manually when needed.  This will grab two CSV from the file system and process them to import data to sql table. This should be run once a month when the CSV file is updated. 
Now I would like to automate this process.  I want to add a step to the existing job that should check for the modified file dates (of two particular files) and compare it to the Today's date and if true, proceed to the next step otherwise not.  I am not sure how to check for the modified date of the files (two files) on the file system and compare to today's date.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a script task to pull the modified date in for comparison, using the following medthod:

[File.GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx)

Comment: Do you mean to create another SSIS with this Script task and compare?

Comment: No you can just add it as a step in your package, I assume you are using a foreach loop container to loop through each file?  If so, add a script task inside of there using the GetLastWriteTime method, and use a precedence constraint to actually limit based on modified date. I just stumbled upon this which is quite similar to what you've got going on:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tim_mitchell/2010/8/23/ssis-conditional-file-processing-in-a-foreach-loop/